# in vim, how to set "args" to the result of a "grep -l"?

Tags: vim, command-line, grep, vi

To illustrate, here's how to do it from the command-line:

```
vim `grep "hello" * -Rl`
```

This opens vim with all the files that have "hello" in them (-l gives the filenames alone). I want to do the same thing, but from within vim.  Conceptually, something like this (which doesn't work):

```
:args !grep "hello" * -Rl
```

I'm open to completely different approaches to achieve this; I'd just like it to be on one line (so it's easy to edit and redo).

---

The answer is to simply use backticks - *but with a key proviso!*  The below does not work for me, because of the **quotes** around `hello`:

```
:args `grep "hello" * -Rl`
```

But it works if I remove them or escape the quotes:

```
:args `grep hello * -Rl`
:args `grep \"hello\" * -Rl`
```

(this was buried in the comments after chaos' answer - I added them here to make them more visible, in case anyone else had this problem)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, this works for me:

```
:args `grep -Rl "hello" *`
```

Running vim 7.0.305.

Comment: thanks, I tried using backticks, but vim doesn't recognized them - instead it interprets "`grep" as a filename.  Have you got your answer to work for you?  If so, I wonder why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yeah, worked fine for me.  Maybe a version thing.  I'm using 7.0.305.

Comment: hmmm, :version gives me:
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jan 31 2007 18:15:57)
Included patches: 1-122

Comment: OK, I upgraded to version 7.1.314, but same problem.  I'm cut-and-pasting your code, so it's not a typo.  Maybe it's a compiler option, or a setting.  But there's so many, it would be hard to know which one.

Comment: I'm not finding anything linking backtick expansion to compile options.  There is something about backtick expansion not working in restricted mode (-Z option at startup), but I don't know why you'd be running under that.

Comment: Restricted mode doesn't produce the same results you're getting anyway; it generates a not-allowed error.

Comment: I guess the question has to be asked: are you sure you're sending backticks?  Could your client be screwing you up, sending something else -- those obnoxious Microsoft-beloved left quote characters or something?

Comment: thanks for that checking - much appreciated! :-).  Experimenting a bit, it seems that it might be the quotes around hello.  This works: :args `grep -Rl hello *`
--- though it turns out it's best not done from one's home dir (what with that -R :-)

Comment: YES. Escaping the quotes also works: :args `grep -Rl \"hello\" *`  so I think that was definitely the problem. Yay, thanks so much, it is really cool to get this working :D

Comment: " starts a comment in Vimscript, which makes using it in Vim commands a bit tricky...

Comment: Ahh, interesting.  Wonder why it messes up for 13ren but not for me.

Comment: I was using backticks for \`ack -l keywords\` and it worked perfectly but when I replaced ack with ag it just turns the whole thing into a filename. Having \`ag -l keywords\` as a file name is sort of bad since when you try to rm it it searches for files and then deletes them. I'm very confused. Every other command I put into backticks works fine.

Answer (score 3):

Try the `args` command:

```
:ar[gs] `grep -Rl "hello" .`
```

If the backticks aren't working for you, are you use you're using a current version of vim?

```
:version
```

Comment: It's version 7, but not the very latest.  I'm checking for a new version now.

Comment: I just upgraded to version 7.1.314, but same problem.  I wonder what the problem is.

Comment: Hi again, it seems it was the quotes around hello - it works fine without them, or if they are escaped. :-)

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you found the issue!  Cheers.