# How to set :args to the result of 'ag -l keywords` in vim

Tags: vim, args

I'm in the process of switching from ack to https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher because of speed issues. Everything would be fine except that I have a command in my vimrc that sets args to the results of an Ack search like so: :args `ack -l keywords`.

```
ag -l keywords
```

does the same thing in my terminal but when I run :args `ag -l keywords` it actually creates a file called `ag -l keywords` which is crazy because if I try to rm it it deletes all the files that the search matches.

Anyway my question is: Why does it work for one command but interprets another as a literal.

This question also deals with a similar issue but the way they solve it doesn't make sense or work for me.
[in vim, how to set "args" to the result of a "grep -l"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033524/in-vim-how-to-set-args-to-the-result-of-a-grep-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backticks should work no matter which command. Are you sure the `ag` command is accessible from within Vim (i.e. it's not just a shell alias or function)? Try executing

```
:echo executable('ag')
```

It should yield `1`.

Comment: It does yield 1. But :args `ag -l hello` yields "`ag -l hello`" [New File].

     :!ag -l scary
Yields app/controllers/builds_controller.rb
app/controllers/customer/orders_controller.rb
app/controllers/customer/builds_controller.rb
app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
app/controllers/images_controller.rb
app/controllers/tank_configurations_controller.rb

So I know the command works. I'm just really confused. I've tested it on two computers running OSX 10.8 and one new ubuntu install.

Comment: What about other commands? And I would try stubbing out the `ag` executable with a simple shell script that just `echo`s a fixed list of files.

Comment: ls and grep -l keywords works fine. I also mapped symlinked ack to ag and it still works fine. So obviously something is different with the return values of ag. If I run the same command in the terminal ack return the values uncolored while ag returns a colored list.
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s10/sh/1f429142-7a6d-4fda-9c62-ecd55bf5b186/787afa217ec47642336f38e3b550c142

Comment: If it use the --nocolor option it prints the same as ack in the terminal but in vim :args \`ag --nocolor -l Controller\` still results in "\`ag --nocolor -l Controller\`" [New File]